# Blender freeze after hair particle system

Tags: modifiers, particles, add-on, hair, error

really strange but im not able to duplicate the particle system from the left wing to the right wing without crashing blender.

I used ctrl + m, x to mirror the wing, maybe some bug here? Also used https://blenderartists.org/t/boundary-aligned-remesh/1149739 to remesh the wings.

i was not able to reproduce the error.

Best, Joseph

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/m4nGKg4D

Comment: copied all objects into a new blender file, now everything works fine again, where is the bug?

Answer (score 0):

If the color in the *Viewport Shading* is set to *Random* it will crash, if it set to *Material* everything works fine.